# setSelected(true) not working first time

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click on button then I have invoked the buttonView.setSelected(true)
method to set button in selected state, but first time button not selected and second time click button get selected.
Code:
main.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/pause"
android:background="@drawable/item_selected" />
```

item_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pause">
</item>

</selector>
```

Initialize Button

```
Button pauseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
```

Click code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
int viewID = v.getId(); 
if(viewID == R.id.pauseButton)
{
    pauseBtn.setSelected(true);
}
}
```

I don't understand why button not selected on first click.

Comment: Someone say what is the question actually

Comment: maybe it would help if you post your java code too.

Comment: Question was why button not get selected in first click (touch) why I have to touch twise to make button selected. Is I have did something wrong in xml files or what I have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pauseBtn.setPressed(true);
```

Read [this](http://android.andrewshu.com/2009/06/statelistdrawable-and.html) blog

Comment: This solution also works on second time press.
Thanks for your quick answer.